# How can I get Wildfly to load my EAR deployments in the correct order?

Tags: java, wildfly

According to [Wildfly's documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly), it should be possible to declare the order by which subdeployments are deployed within an EAR. However, I am not able to get it to respect the order of dependencies I have defined within my application.

The EAR has specified the `initialize-in-order` AND I have specified a dependency chain of `webapp-three -> webapp-two -> webapp-one` in the JBoss-specific file.

Am I missing something about how to declare this?

`application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>ear</display-name>
  <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>webapp-one-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/one</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>webapp-two-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/two</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>webapp-three-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/three</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <sub-deployment name="webapp-one-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="webapp-two-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.wildfly-deployment-order.ear.webapp-one-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="webapp-three-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.wildfly-deployment-order.ear.webapp-two-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I would expect the deployment order to be:

1. `webapp-one`
2. `webapp-two`
3. `webapp-three`

Here is how Wildfly deploys:

`11:27:31,046 INFO  MSC service thread 1-1 [deployment] JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "webapp-two-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
11:27:31,046 INFO  MSC service thread 1-1 [deployment] JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "webapp-three-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
11:27:31,047 INFO  MSC service thread 1-1 [deployment] JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "webapp-one-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though we start deploying all of them at the same time, initialise-in-order means that the individual components in the deployment will be initialised in order, so EJB's Servlets etc in webapp-two will not be started until webapp-one has started.

We still parse the deployments and build deployment metadata in parallel, because there is no reason not to.

Comment: Thanks, Stuart. So the "Starting subdeployment" message does not necessarily correspond to the components within the deployment being started if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: Is there a way to define the order of initialization via dependencies instead of using initialize-in-order? We miss out on some parallelization if that is the only mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a sub deployment. You can define a sub deployment deployment order with dependencies in every sub deployment. You need to add a `Class-Path: webapp-one-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` to the `MANIFEST.MF` file of webapp-two-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war. If you use maven, you can use in the config described in the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-war-plugin-2.4/examples/war-manifest-guide.html) documentation. It puts the dependency entries, defined in the `pom.xml` into the `Class-Path:` section, but this works not, if the dependencies defined as provided. In this case use the following configuration in the `pom.xml`:

```
 <archive>
   <manifestEntries>
     <Class-Path>webapp-one-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</Class-Path>
   </manifestEntries>
 </archive>
```

I found the solution in the *Class Loading in Wildfly* section of the Wildfly documentation posted in the question. In this documentation section is a green box with a green checkmark:

> **Portability**
>   The Java EE specification says that portable applications should not rely on sub deployments having access to other sub deployments unless an explicit Class-Path entry is set in the MANIFEST.MF. So portable applications should always use Class-Path entry to explicitly state their dependencies.